# "you have been shown on the mountain"

Tags: exodus

In Exodus 26:30 (NASB)

> 30 Then you shall erect the tabernacle according to its plan which you have been shown on **the mountain**.

What is "the mountain"?

Comment: Mount Sinai/Mount Horeb. Upon which mountain (with two names) are revealed two covenants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite uncomplicated.  When Moses led the Israelites out of Egypt, we have the following sequence of events:

- Ex 19:1-3 - they arrived at Mt Sinai
- Ex 19:4-25 - Moses relays messages between the God and the people and vis-versa in preparation for  the giving of the law in Ex 20-23.
- During this time Moses ascends and descends the Mountain of Sinai, see Ex 19:11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, 23, etc.
- Moses then received further instructions about the construction of the tabernacle "in the mountain" of Sinai while the Israelites remained camped at its base.  Ex 24:4, 1517, 18.  See also Ex 25:8.

Thus, the entire mountain from which Moses received instruction is Mt Sinai and was constantly referenced in other places such as Ex 26:30, 31:18, 32:1, 15, 34:2, 3, 4, 29, etc.

Mt Sinai was also called Mt Horeb.